# Importing a deck in anki python

Tags: python, anki

I am working on an addon, for anki, which requires me to import a new deck using its python API. I found the function called [test_apkg](https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/627f910635893f8205f7004572ba2ac7f3d987b8/pylib/tests/test_importing.py) which seems to have parts which do that. I tried implementing that below, I am getting no errors, however the deck does not get imported. How do I make my testFunction() import a deck for anki?

```
from aqt import mw
from aqt.utils import showInfo, qconnect
from aqt.qt import *

from anki.importing import *

import os

from anki.collection import Collection as aopen

#from anki.pylib.tests.shared import getEmptyCol



from .shared import getEmptyCol

   
def testFunction() -> None:

    file = "flashcards.apkg"

    col = getEmptyCol()

    apkg = r"path_to_file/flashcards.apkg"
    imp = AnkiPackageImporter(col, apkg)

    imp.run()

# create a new menu item, "test"
action = QAction("Import", mw)
# set it to call testFunction when it's clicked
qconnect(action.triggered, testFunction)
# and add it to the tools menu
mw.form.menuTools.addAction(action)
```

Comment: Maybe using '\' instead of '/' helps?

Comment: @BlazingBlast, Unfortunately that does not. I tried your suggestion. If it where a pathing problem then I would have gotten an error message. I think that I am missing a "create deck" part.

Comment: `test_apkg` is part of an interal unit test, so it means it can access internal functions and there may be some setup code that is executed beforehand to make things work. However, Anki does not officially support any such API to add decks, so I would recommend relying on unofficial APIs such as anki connect, ki, or even simply generating a deck in an other format that Anki can then import (CSV is probably the easiest one).